# Calculating conditional expectation for uniform distribution over a trapezoid

Tags: probability-or-statistics, regions

I have a bivariate uniform distribution, defined over a trapezoid $\Omega$ with vertices $(2, 2), (1, -2), (-2, -2), (-2, 2)$:

$$\vec{\xi} = (\xi_1, \xi_2) \sim \mathcal U (\Omega).$$

How can I represent this distribution in Mathematica and calculate the conditional expectation $E(\xi_1 | \xi_2)$?

Note that I have already made four attempts ([#1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/296105/finding-the-mathematical-expectation), [#2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/296127/plotting-a-regression-line-in-wolfram-mathematica), [#3](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/295620/uniform-distribution-in-trapezoid), [#4](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/296038/uniform-distribution-in-polygon)) without any success.

Comment: This is now your _fifth_ attempt to post the exact same question, and once again it is unclear. I have significantly edited your question, trying to improve it as much as possible. Please, do not go on posting such low-quality questions. Try to make them clear. Help yourself with online translation tools if English is not your native language.

Comment: @Domen I think your excellent edits made the question clear.  (Athough, I would drop the $\vec{\xi} = (\xi_1, \xi_2) \sim \mathcal U (\Omega).$ as it is not necessary given the common loose statistical notation in some questions.)

Comment: @JimB, thanks – I didn't really know how to include the naming ($\xi_1$ and $\xi_2$) of the variables, hence the equation ... Please, feel free to remove it :)

Answer (score 9):

First, you need to set up your trapezoid region. You can use [`Polygon`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Polygon.html):

```
Ω = Polygon[{{2, 2}, {1, -2}, {-2, -2}, {-2, 2}}];
```

Then, you need to prepare your distribution. You want a uniform distribution over this quadrilateral, which you can construct using [`ProbabilityDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProbabilityDistribution.html) and [`RegionMember`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMember.html):

```
dist = ProbabilityDistribution[Boole[RegionMember[Ω, {ξ1, ξ2}]], {ξ1, -2, 2}, {ξ2, -2, 2}]
(* ProbabilityDistribution[Boole[
    (\[FormalX]1 | \[FormalX]2) ∈ Reals && 
    2 + \[FormalX]1 >= 0 && -2 <= \[FormalX]2 <= 2 && 4 \[FormalX]1 <= 6 + \[FormalX]2], 
    {\[FormalX]1, -2, 2}, {\[FormalX]2, -2, 2}] *)
```

You see that the distribution was already automatically "parametrized" into a set of 3 inequalities, which define your trapezoid.

Now, you can use [`Expectation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Expectation.html) together with [`Conditioned`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Conditioned.html) to calculate $E(\xi_1 | \xi_2)$:

```
Expectation[ξ1 \[Conditioned] ξ2 == x, {ξ1, ξ2} \[Distributed] dist] /. x -> ξ2
(* ConditionalExpression[1/8 (-2 + ξ), ! (ξ >= 2 || ξ <= -2)] *)
```

Therefore:
$$E(\xi_1 | \xi_2) = \frac{\xi_2}{8}-\frac{1}{4}.$$

Answer (score 4):

@Domen 's answer is the appropriate answer for "how to represent this function in *Mathematica*" (and should be the selected answer).  But if one didn't have the functions `ProbabilityDistribution`, `RegionMember`, and `Expectation`, then the following brute-force method could be used in a few other languages:

```
(* Joint distribution for a bivariate uniform distribution of area 14 *)
jointpdf[x1_, x2_] := Piecewise[{{1/14, (-2 <= x2 <= 2 && -2 <= x1 <= 1) || (1 < x1 <= 2) && -6 + 4 x1 <= x2 <= 2}}, 0]

(* Marginal pdf of x2 *)
pdfx2[x2_] := Integrate[jointpdf[x1, x2], {x1, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}] //  FullSimplify

(* Conditional mean:  mean of x1 given x2 *)
conditionalMean = Integrate[x1  pdf[x1, x2]/pdfx2[x2], {x1, -2, 2}] // FullSimplify
```

[image: Conditional mean]